# Key Error In Python

Tags: python, text, python-3.x, keyerror

Here is my code

```
with open('yvd.txt') as fd:
    name='Trevor Jones'
    input=[x.split('|') for x in fd.readlines()]
    to_search={x[0]:x for x in input}
    print('\n'.join(to_search[name]))
```

I'm trying to search for a name in a large file and print the information that follows, minus the seperators. Here is an a part of the text file

|Trevor Jones|1|MOV|White Male|Light|10||3000|2500|Old Man Living In Retirement Home|

However, when I run the script I get a key error saying "KeyError: 'Trevor Jones'" which doesn't make sense because Trevor Jones exists in the file.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Print out `to_search` and see what it really looks like.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> text = '|Trevor Jones|1|MOV|White Male|Light|10||3000|2500|Old Man Living In Retirement Home|'
>>> x = text.split('|')
>>> x
['', 'Trevor Jones', '1', 'MOV', 'White Male', 'Light', '10', '', '3000', '2500', 'Old Man Living In Retirement Home', '']
```

Here you can see the problem: `x[0]` is `''`. 
I would just use `text.strip('|').split('|')`

If you are wondering why this is, think about using `'|'.join(x)`, which needs to be able to reconstruct it.